# changing not update on top links title on local.xml

Tags: xml, magento

I changed the local.xml file in magento and reorder the top link of the themes and updated the file and uploaded it on the server as well.. But the changes i made not appearing on the website..

I also cleared the cached folder but still it's not working..

can anyone please let me know how this will update in the website. or what i have to do...

The block i added is :

```
<reference name="wishlist_link">
            <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="fortis/header/top_links_icons">
                <template>page/template/linksblock_icons.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
```

**PATH OF :**

```
\app\design\frontend\fortis\default\layout\layout.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

The position of the wishlist link is controlled bij the local.xml file located in app/code/design/frontend/template/yourtemplate/layout/local.xml .
Search for : wishlist and find :

```
<customer_account>
        <!-- Mage_Wishlist -->
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="wishlist" ifconfig="wishlist/general/active"><name>wishlist</name><path>wishlist/</path><label>My Wishlist</label></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>
```

With the `<before="-">` or `<after="-">` you can control the placement of links relative to other links.

See http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#cms/block-layout-order.html%3FTocPath%3DDesign%2520%2526%2520Theme%7CPage%2520Layout%7CLayout%2520Updates%7C_____2 
for more info on this.